# How to add data into mongo collections

Tags: mongodb

I had following mongo collections structures

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("52204f5b24c8cbf03ca16f8e"),
 "Date" : 1377849179,
 "cpuUtilization" : 31641,
 "memory" : 20623801,
 "hostId" : "600.6.6.6"
}
```

In above collections I had 1000 hostId and every hostId produced cpuutilization and memory every 5 min. So any one suggest me I put my data into single collection or I create separate 1000 collections using hostId like collections name as 100.1.12.2,101.2.10.1....
and I also want indexing on collections for searching records.

Answer (score 0):

From the structure you have shared it would be an intelligent choice to put data into separate records, since the memory and cpuUtilization would always be different. Also, if you store timestamp in Date field, that would always be different.

It would be far more easier to query your database if you store records separately and you could avoid using aggregation as well which will give you better query performance by using appropriate indexes.

So your records should look like below:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("someID1"),"Date" : 1377849179,"cpuUtilization" : 31641,"memory" : 20623801,"hostId" : "600.6.6.6"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("someID2"),"Date" : 1377849210,"cpuUtilization" : 20141,"memory" : 28787801,"hostId" : "600.6.6.6"}

Comment: And how is the OP going to search by hostid or date ? By visiting all the thousand collections ?

Comment: @bsd If for example, you needs to access the data based on cpuUtilization,memory you can build a compound index on it
You would then be able to fetch the data extremely efficiently using indexes.

Same would hold good for other combinations as well, as long as indexes cover the most common access patterns.

If on the other hand, all data is put into single record corresponding to a host, then aggregation framework will be required to be used to do common sorting operations which would not be very efficient

Hope this helps!!

Comment: No, it doesn't help. You cannot build compound index to search __across__ collections. Putting data in separate collections is what you suggested.

Comment: Sorry.My bad! editing this now.. What I intended to say was to put it in same collection but different records.

Comment: Is that even a solution ? How else was the OP inserting data into collections ?

Comment: @NileshRajani If I was separated collections by hostId then I used mongo map-reduced on all collections? If yes then plz. let me know. because using data I want to run some ML algorithm on it.

Comment: @bsd Yeah, you are right. I answered like that because i read the problem incorrectly. I can go ahead and delete my post if that is appropriate.

Comment: @yogesh I am not an expert at Map reduce, but it would help if you can tell us the way your application would access your data. That would help us in giving you a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @NileshRajani I want to shows next coming cpuUtilization and memory of specific hostId if I put my data in separate collections then I do first switch that collections and using data I used my prediction logic but my personal opinion that if I put my data in single collection then it will easy to me figure out what my next cpuUtilization and memory.

Comment: @yogesh Yes, you are correct.

It seems that you want to access trends data based on hostid, date combination. If you build a compound index on hostid, date combination, you would be able to quickly read data even from single collection. **(Note)** I am assuming that you only fetch data from mongodb, but algorithm runs on your client. 

Also, I think you would benefit from sharding based on hostid, since you have about 1000 hosts and each host will be updated fairly regularly.

Answer (score 0):

One collection will be good enough to store the information . One of the thought you have to take care is Write performance , as mongodb locks while writing at database level , Write may be slow. One suggestion I can give to have two or three database which will hold the collections for specific range of host. It help you to write faster . *Beginning with version 2.2, MongoDB implements locks on a per-database basis for most read and write operations.*

Comment: Can you explain me what care should I take at write time in collections

Comment: There is no such care , but I wanted to point out that while writing the log from different host , if one host is not complete the writing the collection and database will be on hold . If you want very real quick write , Have 2-3 database and have predefine the range like host XXX --- YYYY will be in first database and ZZZZ-MMMM in another database . It will keep lock to write limited to one database and performance can be more.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mycol.insert([
{
    title: "MongoDB Overview",
    description: "MongoDB is no SQL database",
    by: "tutorials point",
    url: "http://www.tutorialspoint.com",
    tags: ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"],
    likes: 1
}])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).